# Insert script tag into Angular 4 HTML Component

Tags: javascript, angular, html, photoeditorsdk

I am trying to implement the HTML5 version of the PhotoeditorSDK from this website - https://docs.photoeditorsdk.com/guides/html5/v4/introduction/getting_started

I have tried to implement using the [Angular Github repo](https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-angular-demo) but it would seem that package.json illustrate this only works for Angular 5 & 6 and our app currently is a little outdated being Angular 4.x (and we cannot upgrade to 5 at this time)

Using the HTML5 method is fairly easy in a simple application but within an Angular 4 this seems to be tricky as due to Angular restrictions I am unable to use `<script>` tags within the component.

In the index `<head>` I have added the following:

```
<head>
  <!-- React Dependencies for the SDK UI -->
  <script src="js/vendor/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
  <!-- PhotoEditor SDK-->
  <script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.min.js"></script>
  <!-- PhotoEditor SDK UI -->
  <script src="js/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI.min.css"/>
</head>
```

In the template itself there is a simple `<div>` as follows :

```
<div id="editor" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;"></div>
```

The script tag itself looks as following - and would basically attach an image that would show within the editor to edit etc..

```
<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    var image = new Image()
    image.onload = function () {
      var container = document.getElementById('editor')
      var editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI({
      container: container,
      // Please replace this with your license:    https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/dashboard/subscriptions
    license: '{"owner":"Imgly Inc.","version":"2.1", ...}',
    editor: {
      image: image
    },
    assets: {
      // This should be the absolute path to your `assets` directory
      baseUrl: '/assets'
    }
   })
  }
    image.src = './example.jpg'
}
</script>
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to use `<script>` above directly within an Angular 4 Component - I know this is best practice but what is the best way to do this?

Comment: That's not best practice at all ! the best practice is to save a .js file in your `assets` folder and declare this script in the `angular-cli.json` (or `angular.json` in the newest versions) so that it gets imported at build time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component has an element with id `editor`. This will only be available in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook of the component. Once this is called, the `window.onload` has been called ages ago. Also when the `onload` is called, the element doesn't exist at all yet, so it's also a bad idea to put it there.

Best would be to call the method from inside the `ngAfterViewInit` of your component, and use the `@ViewChild` annotation:

```
declare const PhotoEditorSDK: any;

@Component({
  template: `<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh;" #editor></div>`
})
export class EditorComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('editor') editor: ElementRef<HTMLElement>; 

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const editor = new PhotoEditorSDK.UI.DesktopUI({
        container: this.editor.nativeElement,
        license: '{"owner":"Imgly Inc.","version":"2.1", ...}',
        editor: {
          image
        },
        assets: {
          baseUrl: '/assets'
        }
      });
    });

    image.src = './example.jpg'
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Pierre - that is making more sense now, the error I see now is that the `PhotoEditorSDK` cannot be found (these are loaded within the index.html) but I presume Angular 4 requires this to be loaded differently - how would this work?

Comment: If you are sure they are loaded, you need to add a `declare const PhotoEditorSDK: any;` I'll update my answer. It would be best if they have typings though

Comment: Sorry my fault - I can see the PhotoEditorSDK when I view it directly within the console but when I run `ng serve` to rebuild the app I get the error :
`Cannot find name 'PhotoEditorSDK'` - I added the component in the gist below if that helps :)

https://gist.github.com/gkimpson/cd36b6278169f0e7e3af32c810ef87b1

Comment: I will play around with this a bit more and come back to this thread later as it is almost there and you advice has put me in the right direction :)

Comment: weirdly this doesn't produce any console errors  - however the Photoeditor doesn't appear (nor does it generate the relevant HTML when inspecting the elements)

I have the same PhotoeditorSDK working in an older Angular 1.x application absolutely fine and can see when I inspect the 'editor' element it generates HTML element such `<div class="pesdk-react-editor"><div>` etc..

So i'm not sure why in this Angular 4.x app it doesn't seem to work in the same manner :( I will keep on it - it is probably something simple that I cannot see

Comment: @Zabs are you sure you removed the id and added the `#editor` reference in the template, like in my answer?

Comment: figured it out :) I just removed the eventListener and it seems to load! I got to fix some other problems but the thing is showing now at least - thanks for the advice

Comment: @Zabs perhaps the image doesn't load because you did not add it your assets folder. Is there are 404 in the network request tab for that image? I believe it won't fire a `load` event if there is a 404. But good that it works now :)